# Why doesn't clang require link.exe in ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, clang

I am new to clang. So i was trying to compile a simple c program with clang in ubuntu and windows.

When it comes to Ubuntu, it worked correctly.

When it comes to Windows, it was asking for link.exe of Visual Studio.

Why such a difference?

Is there any information that I can get from other websites, blogs ...

Kindly suggest some answers.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Clang on Windows simply failed to compile my program because it couldn't find any standard header files. It didn't get as far as the linking stage.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu, as any other Unix-like OS, has `ld` program to link executables and libraries. Try running `clang` with `-v` option to see what programs it calls.

Comment: .so for ubuntu ```ld```comes default. but for windows when executing it searches for  linker. Is this correct?

Comment: On windows it depends on environment. If you are working inside MinGW or Cygwin environments, it behaves like in Unix-like OS.  If you are running `clang-cl`, it behaves like Microsoft Visual C++ compiler and uses `link.exe`. There are pretty much environment combinations to list them all.